# Git is driving me nuts, how can I create a new remote branch based on an existing non-master branch?

Tags: git

I'm sure this is very simple to do, but I have followed a number of tutorials and cannot figure this out.

I currently have two branchs on my remote & local machines:

```
master
*search_refactor
```

We want to create a new remote branch called design_refactor and have the code in this new branch to be (initially) a clone of the code in the search_refactor branch.

The purpose behind all of this is that I want to try out some ideas I have on the search_refactor branch, share these with others, but not modify the search_refactor branch.

Our current version of git is 1.6.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a new branch on the remote, you can create it by pushing to the new reference.  E.g.

```
git push origin search_refactor:refs/heads/design_refactor
```

This pushes that state of the local `search_refactor` branch as the new remote `design_refactor` branch.

IIRC you need the `refs/heads` to bypass a safety check that git needs the branch to already exist or for you to be pushing a matching named local branch.

If you wanted to use the state of the *remote* `search_refactor` branch, without any changes that you might have in your local `search_refactor` branch you could use:

```
git push origin origin/search_refactor:refs/heads/design_refactor
```

Once you've done this you can checkout a new local branch based on the remote branch.

```
git checkout -b design_refactor origin/design_refactor
```

(For simplicitly I've assumed that your main remote is called `origin`.)

Comment: Thanks Charles, that solved the issue - very clear explanation!

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible (and make more sense) to create the local branch first, then push to remote? `git checkout -b design_refactor`; `git push origin design_refactor:refs/heads/design_refactor`